# Qt creator HTML5 project -lsqlite3

Tags: application-development

I've download the Ubuntu SDK to make apps. Building a native app went great in QtCreator. But now I'm trying to build an app using QtCreator with HTML5. So I made a new project and chose HTML5 as project template and simply build it. It gives me the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm assuming it cannot find sqlite3 library. But again I'm new using this SDK. What is the best thing to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the SQLite 3 development package ([`libsqlite3-dev` [image: Install libsqlite3-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libsqlite3-dev)) and your linker should be able to link your binary with `sqlite3` lib.

Comment: Yes, you are correct! That worked! I was looking for sqlite3-dev but that was the correct package name. thanks!